# Picking columns with certain amount of letters with potential numbers on top (SQL)

Tags: sql, wildcard

I have a school assignment in which I have an SQL database that has rows with numbers. I'm supposed to do a command which deletes all the columns that begin with 1, have three numbers and potentially has letters on top. This means that some of these have a value like "110P" or something like that, and im supposed to delete them as well. LIKE "1_%_%" however also picks values like "14K" which do not apply.

How do I code

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The regexp functionality might help.

Comment: Show table schema, sample data, desired output, and what full code you've tried so far.

Comment: Also, examples of what is valid and invalid *in text tables* would make the logic clearer.